# Solving nonlinear least-squares problems in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a vba library for solving nonlinear least-squares problems. Usually I use Matlab functions lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata) and lsqnonlin(fun,x0) which have the same nls algorithm but different problem specification. Does anyone know vba library (function) with problem specification as in lsqnonlin(fun,x0)? Of course it is possible to adjust ALGLIB library but it requires time...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This question will probably get a better response on SuperUser, but here's a possible solution:

In Excel, if you create a Scatter chart of your data, you can right-click on the line in the chart, and choose 'Add Trendline'.  This will give you several options for the type ofcurve-fitting you want to do.

However, all the built-in methods are for 'linear' data and will most likely not be optimal for non-linear data.